# Setting Up Jasmine With ASP.Net Core Web Application

Tags: asp.net-core, jasmine

I'm attempting to use Jasmine in a brand new ASP.Net Web Application but I feel like I'm doing it wrong.

My current structure looks like this:

[image]

where the code that I'm writing is in my WebResources folder, the spec-runner.html is in my test folder, and when I build, the gulp file moves both the test and WebResources to the wwwroot.  This allows me to access the `spec-runner.html` file from the browser so I can debug, but all references to the node_modules folder are of course failing since it's outside of the wwwroot folder.

I'm just using the ASP.Net core Web Application to run the `spec-runner.html` file.  Is there an easier way?  If not, how do I determine what files from the node_modules folder to move?  Moving all feels like overkill...

Comment: use Karma instead. You will still be able to debug and you won't need to move any files. https://karma-runner.github.io/2.0/index.html

Comment: so @tehbeardedone use Karma instead of the ASP.Net Core Web Application?

Comment: Use Karma to run your tests, not your .NET core app. It can still open your `spec-runner.html` file in a browser window and you can still debug in the browser. And you won't need to move a single file, you just tell Karma where the tests live when you setup the config and it will find and run them.

Comment: @tehbeardedone, previously I had a spec-runner.html page.  Do I just add that to my karma files config?  When I do, it gives me an error...  Is there something built into Karma-Jasmine that finds all my jasmine tests and runs them automatically?

Comment: Actually @tehbeardedone I think I figured it out.